# Unzip file in java/jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, zip

I am unziping a file using java.

Long ago, somewhere I've got this class in the internet, and I stole and kept it for my own usage. The complete class is:

```
package pubapp.data;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;


public class UnzipUtility {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        // iterates over entries in the zip file
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }

private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
            try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath))) {
                byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This works in my local computer `(windows 7, jdk_1.7, tomcat)` fine. But when I upload war to remote hosting, it does no work as expected. It does not create the sub directories. Web hosting is using Debian/Ubuntu, jdk_1.7, tomcat-7.x

What is wrong with this code in linux?

Comment: Is there an exception?  Is it possibly a file permission exception?  My next question is not exactly related to your issue, but do you actually need to write the zip files to disk - or can you process the contents directly?

Comment: First: there is no exception. Second: I need to upload the zip file itself. Else, It's too big to upload to server. About 100MB.

Comment: I was suggesting that you do upload the zip, but instead of writing the contents of the zip to disk, that you process them directly.  But maybe that's not possible.  At any rate, I think you forgot to close *bos*.